# Change class name all depending on class name value

Tags: jquery, css, class

I currently have `class ="screenPower"` which resides inside `class="screenItem"`.

on `screenItem` I have an click event:

```
$(".screenItem").click(function() {
    var clickedbutton = this;
}
```

**My question is**: How do I change the `screenPower screenOff` to `screenPower screenOn` when clicked? And when `screenOff` is clicked the current active `screenOn` should be turned off. - So in other words - only one screen can have `screenOn` at a time.

What I essentially want to do is something like:

```
if(clicked && == "screenPower screenOff) {
//change target class to screenPower screenOn
//change current active class to screenPower screenOff
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="screenItem">
    <div class="screenImage1">  <span></span>

        <img src="images/img.gif" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="KSRasmussen" />
    </div>
    <div class="screenPower screenOn"></div>
</div>
<div class="screenItem">
    <div class="screenImage1">  <span></span>

        <img src="images/img.gif" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="KSRasmussen" />
    </div>
    <div class="screenPower screenOff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When an screenItem is clicked should it change the class of ALL screenPower elements or only the screenPower element that is a child of that screenItem?

Comment: Imagine having two screens. One is "on" one is "off" - when clicking the one that is "off" it should be turned "on" and the current screen thats was "on" turns into "off" - hope it made sence :)

Comment: so only one screen can be turned on at a time - ill just edit my post to make that more clear. thanks for asking :)

Comment: will they ever both be off? Or is it always one is off, one is on

Comment: "Or is it always one is off, one is on" <- corrrect

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: thanks cfs - im so sorry for probably not being precise enough. you should only be able to toggle the state when clicking a screen that is "off". if you click a screen that is "on" then nothing should happen. So sorry, brain on the weekend already

Comment: Ok, updated my answer again. It now toggles the on/off state of all screenPower elements only if the screenItem that was clicked has a screenOff descendant.

Comment: cfs - so simple - works like a charm. thanks so much for taking the time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `screenItem` is clicked, check if it has any `.screenOff` descendents. If so, then you can find all `screenPower` elements and use the `toggleClass` function to add and remove the `screenOff` and `screenOn` classes:

```
$(".screenItem").click(function() {
    if($(this).find('.screenOff').length > 0) {
        $('.screenPower').toggleClass('screenOff screenOn');
    }
});
```

This assumes that `screenPower` starts as either `screenOff` or `screenOn`, which from your example seems to be the case.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHTpC/3/)**

Comment: and then you can filter logic using .hasClass()

Comment: This will only find the `screenOn` inside the clicked item, not in other `screenItem` blocks. I don't think that is the desired behavior (or I may be misunderstanding the question)

Comment: that's a good question; in re-reading the post I can't tell exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @PeterVR I clarified with the OP and updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".screenItem").click(function() {
   var wasOn = $(this).hasClass('screenOff');
   $(this).removeClass('screenOff screenOn');
   $(this).addClass(wasOn ? 'screenOff' : 'screenOn');

   var clickedbutton = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your click handler:

```
// remove the previous screen On
$('.screenPower .screenOn').removeClass('screenOn').addClass('screenOff');
// make the clicked one active
$(this).find('.screenPower').removeClass('screenOff').addClass('screenOn');
```